# Passing an IEnumerable as an argument in C#, why is this the correct syntax? What does it mean?

Tags: c#, arguments

I try really hard to not let visual studio allow me to fix code without really understanding what's going on. But here it helped me solve a problem and I want to make sure that I understand what's going on before continuing.

Reading the documentation makes me think I'm passing a method as an argument? Why must I have the () at the end of exposureIterator() as opposed to just exposureIterator when passing it as an argument (the first Bar method below is the correct one)? I feel like I must be having an epic brain fart or missing something really important. I really hope it's the former...

Thanks for the help :)

```
public void Foo (Ienumerable iterator)
{
    ...
}

public static System.Collections.IEnumerable exposureIterator()
{
    for (int i = 20; i < 55; i += 5)
    {
        yield return i.ToString();
    }
}

public void Bar()
{
    Foo(exposureIterator());
}
```

VS

```
public void Bar()
{
    Foo(exposureIterator);
}
```

EDIT: Just realized. System.Collections.IEnumerable is simply a return type and it being referenced like that is what confused me. Hurr durrr. Thanks again for the clarification everyone :)

Comment: Foo(IEnumerable iterator) is expecting an IEnumerable. exposeIterator() returns an IEnumerable. So when you call Foo(exposeIterator()) you are passing the result of exposeIterator() [an IEnumerable] to Foo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the result of the method as an argument. The `()` means that there's a function call, and that is evaluated first before the results are set to your `Foo()` method. When you exclude the `()` you are, in fact, passing the method as an argument. This is valid in some cases, but only when the parameter type is a delegate type (read up on delegates here if you aren't sure what I'm talking about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.90).aspx).

You can think of your code like this:

```
public void Bar() {
    // call exposureIterator method and store result in a local variable
    IEnumerable result = exposureIterator();
    // pass local variable containing IEnumerable object to your method
    Foo(result);
}
```

Comment: Haha thanks! This question makes much sense and makes me feel like a derp at the same time. Probably should have gotten more sleep :D

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually passing a method, you are passing the result of a method.

```
public void Foo (Ienumerable iterator)
{
    ...
}
```

`Foo(IEnumerable iterator)` expects an `IEnumerable` object.

`exposeIterator()` returns an `IEnumerable` object. So when you call:

```
public void Bar()
{
    Foo(exposureIterator());
}
```

You are actually passing the result of `exposeIterator()`, which is an IEnumerable. It is equivalent to:

```
public void Bar()
{
    IEnumerator enumerator = exposeEnumerator;
    Foo(enumerator);
}
```

You should also be aware that in certain instances, a method signature may actually ask for a method reference as an argument. In those cases, you would indeed drop the () to pass the argument.

Answer (score 1):

To call `exposureIterator()` you need the () to call the method if it had parameters the () would specify the start and end of those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the IEnumerable returned from exposureIterator() into Foo in the 1st instance; so it is actually executing exposureIterator before calling Foo; in other words you're doing this:

```
public void Bar()
{
    IEnumerable x = exposureIterator();
    Foo(x);
}
```